# Undefined reference Json::Value and Json::Reader

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

When I run the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <C:\Users\User\Documents\jsoncpp-master\dist\json\json.h>
#include <C:\Users\User\Documents\jsoncpp-master\dist\json\json-forwards.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;

    ifstream file("test.json");

   return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
undefined reference to `Json::Reader::Reader()'
undefined reference to `Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)'
```

I am trying to write a program to read the JSON file and this code also has to output the data in the JSON file to be used by another C++ module.

UPDATE

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include "dist\jsoncpp.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;

    ifstream file("test.json");

    return 0;
}
```

I have the changed the code to remove the full link and inserted the dist folder I got after I ran:

```
python amalgamate.py
```

And I entered the header files into C:\MinGW\include

I am now getting a lot of errors in the jsoncpp.cpp file (this is the file I got after running the python command and I did not change it at all). All the errors 
say the same message, which is:

```
first defined here
```

Comment: Where is defined the `Json` class?

Comment: **Linker** error. You have to link with jsoncpp library.

Comment: [OT]: Don't use full path for include. Specify to your build system additional directories to find headers.

Comment: Try the following solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174019/problems-including-jsoncpp-headers

Comment: How did you build your project? How did you link JsonCpp? Did you RTFM about how to use JsonCpp? (Seems not)

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough to just include h files to your source code.
You need to compile jsoncpp.cpp in your project.
Please follow https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp#generating-amalgamated-source-and-header
and add jsoncpp.cpp, json/json.h, json/forwards.h to your project.